# TF.Net versus the NetTopologySuite

Tags: .net, library

In a recent post, a responder made reference to the [Topology Framework .Net](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/).  I'd never heard of it before, having gently used the [NetTopolgySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) (and DotSpatial) before with satisfactory results.  Why would one use TF.Net over NetTopologySuite, or vice versa?  Why does TF.Net exist if NetTopologySuite has been around for quite a while?

Comment: Not familiar with the three libraries myself but its homepage does say that it adds several readers and writers such as MapGuide, FDO and ODP.NET. I agree that it would be helpful to have a complete rundown of the capabilities of each though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quote from [google code hosting](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/) for TF.Net.

> NTS extends JTS with numerous coordinate transformation and other
>   functions, while TF.NET extends NTS further, including additional IO
>   functions and generic classes related to geometry graphs.

It also includes readers for Autodesk ObjectArx, FDO and Mapguide geometries.

In my opinion,there is no advantange of using TF.net over NTS unless you are dealing with some Autodesk data. Except for the readers, other related packages NTS,Quickgraph etc are combined into a single dll, so references are reduced somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

TF.net essentially is NetTopologySuite + Reader/Writer classes for MapGuide/FDO/ObjectARX/ODP geometries.

You would use TF.net if you have a need to work with such geometries in a NTS-compatible form. If you have no need to work with such geometries, then you are better off staying with NetTopologySuite

Also the NTS used by TF.net is quite old last time I tried, which may or may not affect your decision.